# why Div fades on onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I wanted to show a select box when edit icon is clicked.With my code, When i click on the edit icon, the select box appears & it fades out in a second.How can i fix this?

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>Assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('vendor/select2/select2.min.js'); ?>"></script>

    <div id="wrapper">
       <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Material</label>
             <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->ro_material;?>" class="form-control" readonly>
             <a href="" onclick="materialEditDiv();return false;"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
             </div>
          </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6" id="hidddenMaterial" >
           <select name="material" class="form-control">
             
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function materialEditDiv(){
                $('#hidddenMaterial').show();
            }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hidddenMaterial').hide();
    });
    </script>
```

**EDIT**

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>Assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="getData()">

 <div class="col-lg-6" id="hidddenMaterial" style="display:none;">
               <select name="material" class="form-control">
                 <option value="">Select</option>
                  <?php foreach ($material->result() as $rorow) : ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $rorow->material_name;     ?>"><?php echo $rorow->material_name;   ?>
                 </option>
                     <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
          </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function materialEditDiv(){
                    $('#hidddenMaterial').show();
                }
        $(document).ready(function(){
       /* $('#hidddenMaterial').hide();*/
        });
function getData(){
$('#hidddenMaterial').hide(); // tried commenting this line also
}
        </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f4oj76d9/ -  **code snippet**. please have a look on it.

Comment: There's a number of issues with the code provided, eg loading jquery twice, loading jquery *after* select2 (thus removing select2) and mixing onclick with js events.   I suggest you move your onclick=materialEditDiv to a js event that you assign in doc.ready.  What you've described *might* happen if you click the edit before the doc has finished loading, then your existing doc.ready kicks in and hides it (but that's not "fades out") Remove the `$('#hidddenMaterial').hide();` from doc ready and make it hidden on load `<div id='hiddenMaterial' style='display:none;'>` - you also won't get a FOUC.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet ([edit] and click `[<>]`) that *demonstrates* the issue?  Your [provided code](https://jsfiddle.net/1ev3bkpo/) as-is doesn't seem to have an issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m Please have a look at the updated question. i've tried lik eu said. but stll am facing the same issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m https://jsfiddle.net/f4oj76d9/ - code snippet. But there, the edit  icon is not loading

Comment: *edit icon not loading* - that's because it's a font-awesome icon which you've not included - just add "edit" text inside the `i` as that's not relevant to the question.  Changing the `<i>` to `edit` doesn't demonstrate the issue on your snippet.  See [mcve].

Comment: @freedomn-m i could also see it woks in fiddle. But it's not working in my localhost.CAn you tell me any reasons why it behaves so if you know?

Comment: No.  The onus is on you to show us your issue / provide a demonstration (with code).    There's some guesses (provided above), but without being able to see it going wrong, it's impossible to determine the exact cause.

Comment: @freedomn-m i just have the code i give you in the fiddle link.What else i'll show u?

Comment: You're missing the point of showing the *issue*.  Not some code that doesn't cause the problem you've described.  There's clearly *something* causing your issue, but it's not in the code you've provided.

Comment: @freedomn-m Am loading data to this page from my controller. And the page i give in fiddle is my view page.

Comment: Does your page load twice?   Does it only appear then fade away after you click edit?  What if you load the page, wait 5 minutes then click edit?   Is it caused by select2 (which you've commented in the fiddle)?

Comment: @freedomn-m it seems the like page is reloading . after i click the edit icon , the select box appears first, then it disappears , then the page is re-loading. Am not sure am i feeling it disappears beacuse the page get re-loaded.

Comment: Good.  Getting somewhere.  Watch the network tab in the debugger closely.   Could be because of the `<a href=""` - try changing that to `<a href='#'` to stop the page reload - or change it to `<div onclick=..><i ..></i></div>` to remove that completely - may change the style, but one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

How about a delegated click event?

Html

```
<a href="#" class="toggleMaterial"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Js

```
$(document).delegate(".toggleMaterial","click",function(){ 
   $('#hidddenMaterial').toggle();
});
```

Or

```
$(document).on("click",".toggleMaterial",function(){ 
   $('#hidddenMaterial').toggle();
});
```

Full Code

```html
<div id="wrapper">
       <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Material</label>
             <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->ro_material;?>" class="form-control" readonly>
             <a href="#" class="toggleMaterial"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
             </div>
          </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6" id="hidddenMaterial" style="display:none">
           <select name="material" class="form-control">
             
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click",".toggleMaterial",function(){ 
       $('#hidddenMaterial').toggle(); // shows on first click, hides on second
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: i didn't understand that what all changes should i make. should i remove `$('#hidddenMaterial').show();` from `materialEditDiv()`? can you give the full code u meant?

Comment: check the updated code, no need to write an inline  function call

Comment: this answer also reaches to the same situation. it hides the select box in first click itself

Comment: No, no , the hidddenMaterial element will be hidden on load by default. `style="display:none"` by this style tag, reloads have been fixed by adding # to href